# How can I see all the processes that were run during a specific time period

Tags: bash, macos, ps

I know that PS will show me all the currently running processes. But that won't show me anything that's started, then stopped, during some time span. Is there any other way that I can see all the processes that were run during some event?

I'm trying to setup a way of auditing all the processes that ran during a build compilation. I can use PS to check all the running processes at the start of the build, and even run it again at the end. And I can setup a separate thread that will run PS over and over and over again during the build to catch all the processes that might have been run in the middle. But is there some better way of accomplishing this task that I'm not aware of?

This build is being run on a mac, so it uses the mac version of bash.

Comment: [apple.se] would be a better place to ask about MacOS administration tasks.

Comment: On a Linux-y operating system, [sysdig](https://sysdig.com/opensource/) would let you do this trivially (with a Lua API to write your own tooling for real-time analysis, or an available JSON feed). That *does* apply to Docker for Mac, btw (as it runs a virtual machine with a Linux kernel).

Comment: ...for a while, MacOS supported `dtrace`, a tool with comparable capabilities. System Integrity Protection means you might need to make some configuration changes before it can be used on current releases.

Answer (score 0):

After your processes have run you can go to the Console (in the Applications/Utilities Folder) and check the system logs for the time period of interest. Many messages are written so the narrower the time window the better.

Comment: If the question is asking how  to do something manually, vs. how to write code that (say) taps into an API to get a stream of events at runtime, it's off-topic here.